# setState error on unmounted component when with data from Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

When the component below is mounted, everything Firebase related works fine. The issue occurs when the data in Firebase is updated. I then navigate to a different route, therefore un-mounting this component and the setState error occurs.

`Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component`

I have tried turning the Firebase functions 'off' in componentWillUnmount by i still seem to be hit with the error. Any help would be appreciated

```
   constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            firebaseData: {}
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const { referenceId } = this.props.episode || '';
        if (referenceId) {
            this.getFirebaseData(this.removeDissallowedChars(referenceId));
        }
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (this.props.values.referenceId !== nextProps.values.referenceId) {
            this.setState({
                referenceId: nextProps.values.referenceId,
            }, this.fetchWorkflows);
        }
    }
    getFirebaseData(refId) {
        const database = firebase.database().ref(`workflows/sky/${refId}`);
        database.on('value', snapshot => {
            this.setState({ firebaseData: snapshot.val() });
        }, error =>
            console.log(error)
        );
    }
    componentWillUnmount(refId) {
        const database = firebase.database().ref(`workflows/sky/${refId}`);
        database.off();
    }
    removeDissallowedChars(badRefId) {
        /**
         * BE strip characters that Firebase doesn't allow.
         * We need to do the same. Reference id will only contain the characters listed below.
         * Change needed in FE as some of our reference id's currently contain period characters.
         **/
        return badRefId.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9-:/]+/g, '-');
    }
    fetchWorkflows() {
        const { referenceId } = this.state;
        this.props.fetchWorkflows(referenceId);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a class variable that keeps track of whether or not your component is mounted. That would look like this:

```
constructor() {
    //...
    this._mounted = false;
}

componentDidMount() {
    this._mounted = true;
    //...
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    //...
    this._mounted = false;
}
```

Then on any place you set the state after an async request, you can put an if statement that checks whether or not `_mounted` is true.

In your case:

```
    getFirebaseData(refId) {
        const database = firebase.database().ref(`workflows/sky/${refId}`);
        database.on('value', snapshot => {
            // Check if component is still mounted.
            if (this._mounted) {
                this.setState({ firebaseData: snapshot.val() });
            }
        }, error =>
            console.log(error)
        );
    }
```